# How to get Feedjira to work with HTTPS feeds?

Tags: ruby, rss, rubygems, feed, feedzirra

For instance, the following example code returns 0:

```
require 'feedjira'
feed_parsed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse("https://news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories")
puts feed_parsed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ssl_verify_peer to false and that successfully accesses the file.  For instance:

```
require 'feedjira'
feed_parsed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse("https://news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories", {:ssl_verify_peer => false})
puts feed_parsed
```